# Why does Google Vision recognize 'und' locale for images containing just numbers in text?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vision

I've provided an image to the Google Cloud Vision OCR API to be annotated. The image just contained a phone number.

Google Cloud Vision said the locale of the text was 'und'. Does this mean undefined? I'm not finding any information in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, 'und' is not within the code for languages in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages). And since the image didn't contain but numbers then it wouldn't detect a language.

But, the documentation also states that Vision API uses BCP-47 identifiers, and 'und' is listed as a [Non-specific Language Tag](https://www.w3.org/TR/ltli/). You can also find the [clarification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47) that "The special value 'und' (Undetermined) has a 'Scope' of 'special'". Being special defined as:

> 'special' - Indicates a special language code.  These are subtags used
>   for identifying linguistic attributes not particularly associated with
>   a concrete language.  These include codes for when the language is
>   undetermined or for non-linguistic content.

Therefore, "the 'und' (Undetermined) primary language subtag identifies linguistic content whose language is not determined".